# ajax with kendo datasource in jsfiddle using echo api

Tags: ajax, kendo-ui, datasource, jsfiddle

I'm trying to implement an ajax based kendo datasource.

Getting errors like:

```
TypeError: e.schema is undefined
```

..when you exclude the `schema` property declaration...

OR

```
TypeError: r._observable is not a function
```

Above error happens when I try to write schema definition as follows:

```
schema:{
    data:function(response){
        return response;
    }
```

The code I've used is as follows:

```
$(document).ready(function () {
    var ds = kendo.data.DataSource({        
        schema: {
            type:'json'
        },
        transport: {
            type: 'json',
            read: {
                url:'/echo/json/',
                type:'POST',
                data:{
                    json: JSON.stringify(students),
                    delay:1000
                },
                contentType:'application/json',
                processData:false
            }
        }
    });    
    //stripped for sake of brevity
});
```

You can use the following fiddle for starts: http://jsfiddle.net/deostroll/3GqVR/4/

Positive I am missing something on the kendo configuration front...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of issues:

1. You should use the `new` operator to instantiate a data source:

   ```
   var ds = new kendo.data.DataSource({ /* options */ });
   ```
2. For some reason /echo/json/ didn't like the `delay` option. Removing it fixes it.
3. The `dataSource` option of the grid is never set.

Here is the updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/3GqVR/9/

Comment: Thnx. Idea was to set it on button click after a kind of ajax-load.